# Converting integer to a pair of bytes produces unexpected format?

Tags: python, arrays

I am using python 3.8.5, and trying to convert from an integer in the range (0,65535) to a pair of bytes. I am currently using the following code:

```
from struct import pack

input_integer = 2111
bytes_val = voltage.to_bytes(2,'little')
output_data = struct.pack('bb',bytes_val[1],bytes_val[0])
print(output_data)
```

This produces the following output:
`b'\x08?'`

This \x08 is 8 in hex, the most significant byte, and ? is 63 in ascii. So together, the numbers add up to 2111 (8*256+63=2111). What I can't figure out is why the least significant byte is coming out in ascii instead of hex? It's very strange to me that it's in a different format than the MSB right next to it. I want it in hex for the output data, and am trying to figure out how to achieve that.

I have also tried modifying the format string in the last line to the following:

```
output_data = struct.pack('cc',bytes_val[1],bytes_val[0])
```

which produces the following error:

`struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1`

I checked the types at each step, and it looks like bytes_val is a bytearray of length 2, but when I take one of the individual elements, say bytes_val[1], it is an integer rather than a byte array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your observations can be verified from the docs for the [bytes class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers

In Python strings any letters and punctuation are represented by themselves in ASCII, while any control codes by their hexadecimal value (0-31, 127). You can see this by printing `''.join(map(chr, range(128)))`. Bytes literals follow the same convention, except that individual byte elements are integer, i.e., `output_data[0]`.

If you want to represent everything as hex

```
>>> output_data.hex()
'083f'
>>> bytes.fromhex('083f') # to recover
b'\x08?'
```

As of version 3.8 `bytes.hex()` now supports optional `sep` and `bytes_per_sep` parameters to insert separators between bytes in the hex output.

```
>>> b'abcdef'.hex(' ', 2)
'6162 6364 6566'
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info! I tried adding .hex() and it produces a string of the correct hex sequence (0100083f00000000, <class 'str'>), so that's great! However, I need to pack it into a message I am trying to send in a format starting with b for binary data and containing hex escape sequences, like this: b'\x01\x00\x08\x3f\x00\x00\x00\x00'. Do you know if there is any way to accomplish that without editing the resulting string manually?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the key to that is never even using struct.pack. I can just create a bytearray using bytearray(2), then fill in the values from bytes_val values, then convert to a bytes() array and use that. It still has the ? but now I'm thinking that's as expected rather than a mistake. I think I just didn't have any integers below 127 in my test strings

Comment: @JohnDoe It does seem that a `bytes` object will suffice for sending your data, however you construct it. You have to remember that the *representation* of an object is not always indicative of the underlying value it holds. It's the same as doing 0xff, 0b11111111, or 255. It's all the same integer value under the hood. There is no "hex value of an integer". An integer is stored one way in the machine, but we can choose to represent it however we want. It could even be shown to you as a hieroglyph (it doesn't) and its functionality wouldn't change at all.

Comment: Haha, well put. Thanks for the clarification, and all the help!